# Concept - Serving dynamic content based on URL path?

Tags: php, javascript

For example,

the user types in,

```
www.foob.com/some_path
```

I don't want to actually have a some_path folder for every different identifier the user might use ... for example if it is a person's name, as seen in many social apps.

```
www.foob.com/some_path1
```

However, i would like to read it in as a variable and serve the relevant content

JavaScript

```
var foo = 'some_path1'
```

PHP

```
$foo = 'some_path1';
```

How do I get 'some_path1' into foo?

**Note**

some_path is a variable, it might contain

```
some_path_1
some_path_2
some_path_3
```

Clarification

So take facebook.com

if you go to

```
www.facebook.com/your_name
```

it's not like there is a different directory for all 1 billion users.

A generic page is served populated with user specific data.

How do I get the id your_name?

Comment: You should use a rewrite rule to write it to `www.foob.com/somescript.php?foo=filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get this information out with PHP. If you want it in JavaScript, take a look at the `window.location` object (probably `window.location.href` or `window.location.pathname`). Both might require a bit of parsing to only grab the part that you want, though.

Regarding the rewrite rule to send these requests to your script, I'd use something like this, which will redirect all requests for files that aren't found elsewhere through app.php. This should go in an .htaccess file on the root of your site.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In that case, you'll want to intercept these requests with an .htaccess file, and direct them all to your PHP file that's routing the requests.

Comment: Added a rewrite rule above that will redirect any requests for files that aren't found through app.php

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you do. It checks to make sure Apache has the rewrite module enabled, and then sets up the rules.

Comment: So, in this case app.php is routing the requests?

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Yep, that's correct. This is where `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` comes in, to check what the request URL is and route it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup `www.foob.com/some_path` to point to a PHP script URL with `index.php?q=some_path` or similar in your [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Then it's just a matter of serving different content based on `$_GET['q']` in the PHP file.

or to use it in Javascript:

```
echo '<script>...var q = ' . $_GET['q'] . ';</script>';
```

Comment: You mean the parameter could have any name?

Answer (score 1):

Add a [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file to your root directory.

***.htaccess***

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1   [L]
```

You can add something similar to this at the top of your `index.php` page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> MyWebsite <?php echo '~'.ucwords($desired_page); ?> </title>
    <?php
        $page_array = array(
          "home", "blog", "news",
          "links", "about", "contact"
        );

        $desired_page = (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) ? 
          $_REQUEST['page'] : "home";

        if(!in_array($desired_page, $page_array))
          $desired_page = "error";
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li <?php if($desired_page=="home")
              echo("class=\"current\""); ?>>
            <a href="home">Home</a></li>
          <li <?php if($desired_page=="blog")
              echo("class=\"current\""); ?>>
            <a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li <?php if($desired_page=="news")
              echo("class=\"current\""); ?>>
            <a href="news">News</a></li>
          <li <?php if($desired_page=="links")
              echo("class=\"current\""); ?>>
            <a href="links">Links</a></li>
          <li <?php if($desired_page=="about")
              echo("class=\"current\""); ?>>
            <a href="about">About Us</a></li>
          <li <?php if($desired_page=="contact")
              echo("class=\"current\""); ?>>
            <a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--end menu-->

      <div id="content">
        <?php
          /*Includes specific page content*/
          include("content/".$desired_page.".php");
        ?>
      </div> <!-- end #content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe his `app.php` handles redirects similar to the way mine gets the desired page from an array of valid pages, but I could be wrong. Well, this is an approach I have taken. I store just the content of each page in separate html files or in a database, then I just include them in the index dynamically. You never have to leave the index page, because the content will be swapped out. I am just giving you an idea.