# Different website content based on url path

Tags: web, url, apache2

I have my own apache2 webserver and I am struggling in creating different websites with same structure but different content based on url path.

I have  `www.mysite.com` and I want to serve different same sites with different content having different paths.

I.e `www.mysite.com/smth1` and `www.mysite.com/smth2` just like Instagram and Facebook do using `www.instagram.com/profilename`.
The website is the same but the content is different.

Assuming that Instagram doesn't have billions of folder for every profile how is this made?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938238/concept-serving-dynamic-content-based-on-url-path) question before but I have not been able to find a solution